# Orchard CMS Direct Database Querying

Tags: sql, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I accept that this is frowned upon but if someone can humor me that would be great.

Id like to call data from an orchard module using a sql string. To do this I assume i need to get the table prefix if specified when creating the tenant and also the feature prefix for the  module.

So for example.

```
string tenentPrefix = //Wherever I get it from?
string modulePrefix = //Wherever I get it from?

string sql = string.Format("select * from {0}{1}MyTableName",tenentPrefix, modulePrefix); 
//MyTableName obviously being the name of the model
```

Your help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inject `ShellSettings`, then you can access `DataTablePrefix` on it. That answers the first part. For the second part, hopefully you know the module name, so it should be easy to translate it into the table name by replacing the dots with underscores. `ShellBuilder.CompositionStrategy` does it this way:

```
var extensionDescriptor = feature.Descriptor.Extension;
var extensionName = extensionDescriptor.Id.Replace('.', '_');
```